# Punctuation inside or outside quotes

Tags: punctuation, quotes

My question is in regards to how to deal with punctuation and quotes. For instance:

> „Hallo,“ sagte sie.

> „Hallo“, sagte sie.

Which one is correct?

> „Hallo?“ sagte sie.

> „Hallo?“, sagte sie.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in English and German when handling punctuation and quotes. It depends on the context of the statement.

Punctuation marks that belong to what is reproduced literally are placed before the closing quotation mark.

Punctuation marks that belong to the accompanying clause are placed after the closing quotation mark. Both the quoted sentence and the accompanying sentence retain their exclamation and question marks.

Sample 1:

> "Immer diese Regeln!", sagte Thorsten.

Sample 2:

> "Nein", rief sie, "fass das nicht an!"

Comment: Sample 2 does not correspond to a wide-spread convention in English to place the comma before the closing quotation mark (*"Nein," rief sie*). Which means that English and German do handle this differently.

Comment: I didn't do that either, the comma is AFTER the closed quotation marks in sample 2…

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what the answer is saying. Where does the comma go in English and where does it go in German? Is there a difference or not?

Comment: There is a difference in AE and BE. In American English, a quote that comes at the end of a sentence will contain a period inside the final quotation marks. In British English, periods and commas only go inside quotation marks if the original quoted material also had those punctuation marks (same as in German).